# HTTP end point error while try to run in Testnet port

Tags: stellar-core, private-network

I am relatively new to this stellar-core testing and this is the first post of me on stack exchange, if there is any wrong format or mistake, please tell me. I am here because I have met some problems with HTTP end point error.

### Environment

Linux Ubuntu 17.10 and two Stellar-core from Github (I want to set up a private network with two nodes now, do I need two stellar-core installation, cuz that is what I am doing now).

I did not set up horizon, and I am using SQLITE3 as the database. The port I use is 11626 and 11628 (apparently I cannot use the same port when I am running two nodes in two stellar core).

Two configuration files:

The first one:

```
HTTP_PORT=11628 PEER_PORT=11627 PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=false RUN_STANDALONE=false

ALLOW_LOCALHOST_FOR_TESTING=true

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Test SDF Network ; September 2015"

/*stellar-core-1*/

NODE_SEED="XXX"
NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true

KNOWN_PEERS=[ "core-testnet1.stellar.org",
"core-testnet2.stellar.org", "core-testnet3.stellar.org"]

DATABASE="sqlite3://stellar.db" UNSAFE_QUORUM=true FAILURE_SAFETY=1

/*The public keys of the Stellar testnet servers [QUORUM_SET] */

THRESHOLD_PERCENT=60 # rounded up -3 nodes out of 5 VALIDATORS=[
"GD6NDWEPXSUTS7UNEUK2DMDGHVAI265GBGZMBW6VUPWZZNMWUBW23EEH  core2",
"GDKXE2OZMJIPOSLNA6N6F2BVCI3O777I2OOC4BV7VOYUEHYX7RTRYA7Y  sdf1",
"GCUCJTIYXSOXKBSNFGNFWW5MUQ54HKRPGJUTQFJ5RQXZXNOLNXYDHRAP  sdf2",
"GC2V2EFSXN6SQTWVYA5EPJPBWWIMSD2XQNKUOHGEKB535AQE2I6IXV2Z  sdf3"]


[HISTORY.local] get="cp /home/dennis/stellar-core-1/history/vs/{0}
{1}" put="cp {0} /home/dennis/stellar-core-1/history/vs/{1}"
mkdir="mkdir -p /home/dennis/stellar-core-1/history/vs/{0}"

[HISTORY.h1] get="curl -sf
http://stellar-01.xyz.info/stellar-core/history/vs/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.h2] get="curl -sf
http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_001/{0}
-o {1}"

[HISTORY.h3] get="curl -sf
http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_002/{0}
-o {1}"

[HISTORY.h4] get="curl -sf
http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_003/{0}
-o {1}"
```

The second one:

```
HTTP_PORT=11626 PEER_PORT=11625 PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=false
RUN_STANDALONE=false

ALLOW_LOCALHOST_FOR_TESTING=true

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Test SDF Network ; September 2015"

/* stellar-core-2 */
NODE_SEED="XXX"

NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true

KNOWN_PEERS=[
"au.stellar.ibm.com",
"br.stellar.ibm.com",
"ca.stellar.ibm.com",
"no.stellar.ibm.com",
"it.stellar.ibm.com",
"hk.stellar.ibm.com",
"in.stellar.ibm.com",
"uk.stellar.ibm.com",
"us.stellar.ibm.com"]

DATABASE="sqlite3://stellar.db" UNSAFE_QUORUM=true FAILURE_SAFETY=0

/*The public keys of the Stellar testnet servers [QUORUM_SET] */
THRESHOLD_PERCENT=75 # rounded up -3 nodes out of 4 VALIDATORS=[
"GBQDAG7IV2LFT5SVWCYZZCTLYBS7BNY74BU7NPES35HA3D3CQU2RSGUM  core1"
"GCKWUQGSVO45ZV3QK7POYL7HMFWDKWJVMFVEGUJKCAEVUITUCTQWFSM6", 
"GBUJA3Z5TLAKLI5MEH4TETLXJBQVSVW74MNEKP5UUHTP3IMLNSUPOTVA",
"GB2HF2NHRKKFZYFDGD7MUENOYROOEK7SWYV2APYOODP6P7BUJTLILKIL",
"GDRA72H7JWXAXWJKOONQOPH3JKNSH5MQ6BO5K74C3X6FO2G3OG464BPU",
"GAEEH4TBR7YQQWKJ2FIT57HXZZTMK2BX5LY4POJUYFSEZ7Y2ONHPPTES",
"GBJ7T3BTLX2BP3T5Q4256PUF7JMDAB35LLO32QRDYE67TDDMN7H33GGE",
"GCH3O5PTCZVR4G65W3B4XDKWI5V677HQB3QO7CW4YPVYDDFBE2GE7G6V",
"GAENPO2XRTTMAJXDWM3E3GAALNLG4HVMKJ4QF525TR25RI42YPEDULOW",
"GARBCBH4YSHUJLYEPKEPMVYZIJ3ZSQR3QCJ245CWGY64X72JLN4A6RSG" ]

[HISTORY.local] get="cp /home/dennis/stellar-core-2/history/vs/{0}
{1}" put="cp {0} /home/dennis/stellar-core-2/history/vs/{1}"
mkdir="mkdir -p /home/dennis/stellar-core-2/history/vs/{0}"
```

### Error

```
2018-05-01T14:56:42.424 GAAAA [Overlay INFO] New connected peer
174.222.139.94:11625 2018-05-01T14:56:42.425 GAAAA [Overlay INFO] New connected peer 54.211.174.177:11625 2018-05-01T14:56:42.993 GAAAA
[Overlay ERROR] readHeaderHandler error: End of file
:54.211.174.177:11625 [TCPPeer.cpp:397] 2018-05-01T14:56:42.993 GAAAA
[Overlay INFO] Dropping peer GAAAA@54.211.174.177:11625
2018-05-01T14:56:44.424 GAAAA [Overlay WARNING] idle timeout
2018-05-01T14:56:44.424 GAAAA [Overlay INFO] Dropping peer
GAAAA@174.222.139.94:11625 2018-05-01T14:56:44.424 GAAAA [Overlay
WARNING]  connectHandler error: Operation aborted.
```

and

```
2018-05-01T14:01:23.753 GAAAA [Overlay INFO] Dropping peer
self@67.164.106.60:11625 2018-05-01T14:01:23.753 GAAAA [Overlay ERROR]
TCPPeer::drop shutdown socket failed: Transport endpoint is not
connected [TCPPeer.cpp:195] 2018-05-01T14:01:25.543 GAAAA [Overlay
WARNING] idle timeout 2018-05-01T14:01:25.543 GAAAA [Overlay INFO]
Dropping peer self@179.252.252.131:11625 2018-05-01T14:01:25.543 GAAAA
[Overlay WARNING]  connectHandler error: Operation aborted.
2018-05-01T14:01:25.544 GAAAA [Overlay WARNING] idle timeout
2018-05-01T14:01:25.544 GAAAA [Overlay INFO] Dropping peer
self@35.173.249.57:11625 2018-05-01T14:01:25.544 GAAAA [Overlay
WARNING]  connectHandler error: Operation aborted.
```

My speculation:
1. Do I have to use horizon and bridge server?
2. Why my transport end point is not connected?
3. should I use Postgre instesd of SQLITE3?

And when I try to run stellar-core --c info, I was not able to get the result, instead, I get

```
2018-05-01T15:44:54.831 GAAAA [default INFO] http failed(1) port: 11628 command: info
```

Please tell me what I should do, and ask me questions and more information if I did not describe it clearly.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to start one-by-one with using port 11626 for one node first. If it works, then start the second one at another port.

---

1. Stellar Core is the part to do network communication. Horizon & bridge server are like optional plugins building on top of the local Core, so you may omit them.
2. Would you confirm that you are not behind a firewall? At my working place, some ports (e.g. 11625) were blocked and I faced similar issues. Outbounding connection via this port was not viable, so I could not sync to the testnet.
3. I know SQLITE should work, but not sure with SQLITE3. You may switch to try with Postgres and see if your issue persists (most of us are using Postgres with no problem).

---

Guess that you took reference on [this testnet example config](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/stellar-core_testnet.cfg).

As I could not search for `http://stellar-01.xyz.info`, please try with dropping `[HISTORY.h1] get="curl -sf http://stellar-01.xyz.info/stellar-core/history/vs/{0} -o {1}"`.